# Sorting a view by dropdown

Tags: ajax, drupal, sorting, view

Hey, i've been looking around for a ajax dropdown sorter for my Views in Drupal.

Unfortunatly, i haven't found alot of usefull information about this subject.

Can anyone tell me if theres a solution already available or can help me started on a custom module by telling me which hooks i should use?

Comment: Have you tried exposing the field that you wish to sort by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Unfortunately I wasn't able to sort the data from the database which is by far the best way. I was however able to take the data and sort it with PHP using a preprocessor function. Depending on the name of your view, setup a function similar to the following:

```
function templatename_preprocess_name_of__view(&$vars)
{
    //Super sweet sorting code goes here
}
```

The name of your view needs to follow the name of the template file that it is driven by, if there isn't on you should create one. Make sure to change dashes to underscores in your function name. Hope this is helpful. If you find a way to do it from the DB I'm all ears because that would be super awesome.